# Radius server benchmark

Tags: radius, benchmark

I wrote some module for FreeRadius and need to check it's performance. Using radclient is not OK because radius server is multi threaded and radclient not - it waits for an answer for previous request before sending next one.

Do anyone have any ideas about radius server benchmark tool (like apache `ab` or `httperf`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't want to reinvent the wheel and also write benchmark tool with my module ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just spawn a bunch of radclient processes in the background, to simulate simultaneous connections.  It wouldn't be terribly precise...then again, since radclient is single threaded, then it should be a one to one mapping (spawning 300 simultaneous background process would be equivalent to 300 simultaneous users).  Of course, since your automating the connections, your going to hit the Radius server harder then 300 actual users, unless they are all authenticating at the exact same time, but it might meet your purposes.

If your into scripting, you could write a quick Perl script to also perform the authentication, but you would probably have to spawn child processes, or use threading, both of which are more complicated then the above, but may give you more control.

Comment: Yep, this is one of the options and I already started developing such on python + pyrad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [RadTest](http://www.radutils.com/) or [NTRadPing](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/14377.html)?

Comment: As I see RadTest is just a frontend to radclient utility compiled in windows - it have same limitations. NTRadPing can send only 1 packet at once - no benchmark functionality.

Comment: Ah ok, understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAS Simulator from Aradial Technologies http://www.aradial.com/